# Indexed lists and selected cells in iOS

Tags: ios, uitableview, selection, indexing

I have a quite long list of items I need to show the user and request him for select one. This list is really too long for making a simple table with prototype cells and righ selection indicator, so I've though about using an indexed table. But since this type of table does not allow to have a selection indicator because of the right indexes scroll view, how could I manage this scenario?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can provide a search feature for your table view. Look [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/16873/how-to-add-search-into-a-table-view) for more details.

After result is filtered, you can apply tick mark on the selected cell.

You can apply a checkmark by using following code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
```

}

Comment: Thanks! Is this suitable for grouped table views, or only for plain ones?